# GeoServer WFS sortBy (v2.0.0) with multiple layers?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, query, getfeature

I'm using WFS with multiple layers, but the results are sorted by layer, not by the full result set.

For instance:

**Layer A**

- a
- b
- c
- d

**Layer B**

- a
- b
- c
- d

I want the results be a **single list sorted by name** (all layers have the attribute "name"), no matter from which layer the result is, I just need a global order.

**Layers result**

- a
- b
- c
- d
- e
- etc...

Here is my example query:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=EPSG:4326&request=GetFeature&count=10&startIndex=0&typeNames=(myworkspace:layerA)(myworkspace:layerB)&propertyName=myworkspace:layerA:name,myworkspace:layerA:geom,myworkspace:layerB:name,myworkspace:layerB:geom,&cql_filter=(name ILIKE '%example%25');(name ILIKE '%example%25')&sortBy=name
```

What would be a good sortBy syntax?

Comment: I do not believe that WFS has any support for what you try to do, that is, to union two featuretypes on the fly. If there is such support it should be found from the the standard http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html

Comment: Your example is not at all clear. No `e` is mentioned in the *before* results, but is found in the *after*. And why isn't it `a a b b c c d d`?

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes your are right, forget about "e", it's just a bad example.  "a a b b c c d d" is what I expect to receive from the call. I mean, a unique list sorted, and not sorted only at layer level. That is what an end-user expect as a normal search results.  Any idea how to achieve the sorting in Geoserver layers?

Comment: Then the client will need to reorder the results, or you can create a view that combines the 2 tables and publish that view as a layer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will explore the second option first.